# How to Know the Given Date is UTC or Local in C#

Tags: c#

I am passing the Date Like DateTimeOffSet in postman and I just want to find out the date is utc or Local,

```
{
  "fromDate": "2019-11-06T09:55:51.695Z",
  "toDate": "2019-11-06T09:55:51.695Z"
}
```

what i have tried is ,

```
var fromDateKind = fromDate.UtcDateTime.Kind;

var toDateKind = toDate.UtcDateTime.Kind;
```

I need to check the given FromDate and ToDate is UTC,
How to know the given Date is UTC or Local

Comment: The trailing "Z" is supposed to mean Zulu time, i.e., UTC. You should just be query the `Kind` property directly on `fromDate` or `toDate` objects.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators

Comment: I am Passing fromDate and Todate as a DateTimeOffSet, i cant able to find the kind property directly on these objects

Comment: Beware... The z utc DateTime will be put into a converted local version of that DateTime.  Use a datetimeOffset class

Comment: If you just deserialize it to a datetime without setting DateTime kind _first_.  DateTime can either be local, or utc, and that's it.  DateTimeOffset doesn't act like that

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this myself but I think the DateTime has a `Kind` enum property of type `DateTimeKind`.

DateTimeKind enum documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind).

DateTime.Kind property documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind).

It should be as easy as `if (dateTimeObject.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local) {...}`